# Symfony2 - A bundle is a feature... but what's a feature?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying for the first time to build an application using the Symfony2 framework. However there is so much thing to learn and my brain is kind of saturated with all the videos/blog posts/tips/docs and I feel kind of overwhelm by all this information. I want to start my project the right way and be sure that my architecture will be good. I kind of get the notion of "Bundle". It's meant to be all information related to a feature. But then I ask myself... what is a feature? How do we define a feature?

I'll take a trivial example from my project. I have a user that can signup/login to their account. Is the Login a feature itself? Or is the whole admin interface the feature?

I also have a second example. In my application, my user can upload files to the server. Is the uploader suppose to be in a Bundle (File validation, Copying the file, Resizing image)? I know that my uploader will be use several times (to upload a logo, image of products, etc.) and I obviously want to reuse my code once it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bundle is a group of classes which implement one thing *or* bundles are the glue between a library and te framework. For instance, when creating a blog the main bundle will be the BlogBundle. You also what a comment system, so it also has a CommentBundle. For the menu, you use the KnpMenu library, and thus the KnpMenuBundle. To make de page dynamic, you also use the SonataBlockBundle and SonataAdminBundle.

These are all features.

To answer you cases: All admin stuff is one bundle. But this admin bundle does not include an user system, that's the task of an UserBundle (e.g. FosUserBundle).

In your second case: You have a MediaBundle to handle the upload of specific files (which you configure in the configuration). You also have a UserBundle for the user system and some sort of AdminBundle to keep control of the project.

Comment: Interesting stuff, does that mean that a single page can load multiple Bundle? 

Let's say my AdminBundle Twig generates a menu depending on the USER_ROLE from FosUserBundle. Then my MediaBundle Twig generates my uploader ?

Comment: Yes, sure. In a single request, a lot of bundles are used (if you do it the correct way)